# eog with eog_panorama only works once after reboot

Tags: nvidia, eog, panorama

I gave got a notebook running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and tried to view spheric panorama images on it. Therefore I installed and activated the [Panorama Viewer](https://github.com/Aerilius/eog_panorama) plugin. This works fine, but only once, for the first image loaded `eog 230809/DJI_0075.JPG`. Syslog is showing:

> gnome-shell[3113]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2c00007

and in the terminal appears

> libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
> WebView warn: THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_depth_texture extension not
> supported.

But it works fine with these messages for the first image. Closing `eog` and starting it with the same image again shows the same messages except for the second in on console which now is

> WebView error: Script error.: :0:0

Repeating this several times shows again

> libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
> WebView warn: THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_depth_texture extension not
> supported.

But it keeps just showing the plain image and not the panoramic view.

The notebook has a GeForce GT 750M and the problem looks like some GL trouble. Any idea how to check?

Logout and login again changes nothing. After reboot it works again just for the first image loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Because it looked like some GL problem, I finally had a look at my Nvidia driver. No idea why, but just installing the latest one `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-dkms-535` solved that problem in my case. The message

> WebView warn: THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_depth_texture extension not supported.

still occurs but can be ignored. So with this driver the Panorama Viewer plugin is a great tool to view my panorama images.